# Can Sketchup turn a circle into an ellipse when given a degree

Tags: sketchup

I haven't used Sketchup but will learn it if it can do the following.

I have a flat piece of sheet metal tilted at 28 degrees (imagine it lying on  the slope of a roof).

A cylinder with a 100mm diameter needs to pass, perfectly plumb, through the tilted sheet. So the hole in the sheet must be elliptical.

Can that hole be created in Sketchup and printed out actual size, to use as a cutting template?

Comment: Get a plastic pipe 100mm diameter from your local hardware/diy store. Cut the end off at a 28 degree angle. Put pipe on metal sheet and draw around it. Job done.

Comment: I understand that it could be done like that, but the pipe is old black iron waste pipe and and is not the same O.D. as modern PVC, and I'm trying to be as exact as possible to make the solder joint a clean and strong one. And cutting black iron isn't all that easy, assuming I could find a piece with the identical O.D. as the old one.

Comment: Ah. So not that easy then :/

Comment: But your suggestion would be a clever one over on DIY :)

Comment: Have you thought about asking over there? They are a smart bunch :)